# Linking usages of constants to their definition in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a Python class that has a member VALID_KEYS, defined as

```
VALID_KEYS = [
    Keys.UP,
    Keys.DOWN,
    Keys.RIGHT,
    Keys.LEFT,
    Keys.SPACE,
    'r',
    'b',
    'y'
]
```

where Keys is selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys. I have an intersphinx link set up, so I can reference this class in my docstrings, but I'd like the documentation of this attribute to show the symbols rather than the values of these keys, and link to the original docs.

Currently, when using autodoc I get

> VALID_KEYS = ['\ue013', '\ue015', '\ue014', '\ue012', '\ue00d', 'r',
>   'b', 'y']¶

which is harder to understand than my desired:

> VALID_KEYS = [selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.UP, selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.DOWN, selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.RIGHT, selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.LEFT, selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys.SPACE, 'r',
>   'b', 'y']¶

I'd rather not have to reproduce the values in documentation directly, but would be willing to for clarity.